# Custom plugin with Bottle to return datetime as JSON?

Tags: python, json, serialization, bottle, python-datetime

I am unfamiliar with the correct Bottle syntax, as such I am left with this error:

> TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Here is my attempt:

```py
from bottle import Bottle, JSONPlugin, app, route, run, static_file
from json import JSONEncoder, dumps as jsonify
from datetime import datetime


# http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#ignore-trailing-slashes
class StripPathMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, e, h):
        e['PATH_INFO'] = e['PATH_INFO'].rstrip('/')
        return self.app(e, h)


# https://github.com/defnull/bottle/issues/287
class MyJsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return str(obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


@route('/api')
def latest_api_version():
    return {'api_version': 0.1, 'latest_as_of': datetime.utcnow()}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp = Bottle(autojson=False)
    myApp.install(JSONPlugin(json_dumps=lambda s: jsonify(s, cls=MyJsonEncoder)))

    run(app=StripPathMiddleware(myApp()), debug=True)
```

How do I get Bottle's JSON parser to return datetime timestamp data without error?

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Giving us a dozen lines of code and telling us there's an error in it somewhere isn't going to get you very far. The kind of error is practically the *least* useful part of the traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out this really simple solution which is [also mentioned](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/287#issuecomment-5835450) in the bugtracker:

```
from bottle import install, JSONPlugin

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Bottle(autojson=False)
    app.install(JSONPlugin(json_dumps=lambda s: jsonify(s, cls=MyJsonEncoder)))
```